# Visualisation of the cubic curve $C: y^2 z − x^3 − x^2z − xz^2 − z^3$

Tags: algebraic-curves, visualization

To get some insight on the zero locus of the cubic curve, I've tried a couple of online visualisers on Google and mostly failed to generate the plot (run time errors...) except [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=3d%20plot&assumption=%7B%22MC%22%2C%20%223d%20plot%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%223DPlot%22%2C%20%223dplotfunction%22%7D%20-%3E%22y%5E2%20z%20%E2%88%92%20x%5E3%20%E2%88%92%20x%5E2z%20%E2%88%92%20xz%5E2%20%E2%88%92%20z%5E3%22) which gave me the following;
[image]

Is this visualisation correct??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe first divide by $z^3$ in order to get inhomogeneous coordinates? This yields

$$
C':y^2-x^3-x^2-x-1=0 \quad(z\neq0)
$$
(which is effectively using $z=1$). And for $z=0$ if follows $x=0$ and hence $y\neq 0$, sometimes called *"point at infinity"*.

With the dimension down to 2 it's easier to visualize, like in this [Desmos plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0hzvwh8csj).

[image: Desmos plot of inhomogeneous curve]